# Forms implementing the same method

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

I have two forms Form A and Form B, which I will use to input information onto an XML file. Now, these two forms will have to call some methods which are basically the same (same name, same implementation).

I can't use a base class in this context, since Form A and Form B already inherits from <kbd>System.Windows.Forms.Form</kbd>. Should I just use an interface that these two forms will implement? I'm doubting that this would be the best approach since the methods they need are the same.

Could you suggest a better approach to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for code reuse and following so called "DRY" principle , you  need to do "EXTRACT CLASS" re factoring to avoid code duplication.

If the above sentence looks so generic so in layman terms , create a Utility Class which is the perfect candidate if you do not want to have different implementation in different form and move the code to utility static class.

```
public static  class Utility
{
    public static void WriteToXML()
    {
        // come code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class where common functions in your project are stored. You can call these functions in any of your forms.

```
namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public class GenericFunctions
    {
        public static void WriteToXML()
        {
         // come code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to introduce a base form that Form A and Form B inherit from:

```
public partial class BaseForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void  CommonMethod()
        {

        }
    }


public partial class FormA : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LocalMethod()
    {
        CommonMethod();
    }


}

public partial class FormB : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LocalMethod()
    {
        CommonMethod();
    }


}
```

That said, if your common code doesn't involve any UI-related stuff, then @Gian Acuna has the correct answer where you can just create a separate class with static methods.